# AWS S3 to Oracle ( Raw ) using sqoop

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, sqoop, sqoop2

Am getting list of EmployeeID as output as part of my EMR result ( in S3) . One of the sample value is F576334E17894499B6334E178974990B . I want to load this to a Oracle table which is EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEEID RAW(16)) using sqoop. But its failing . Can any one please help?

I tried sqoop export . But failing.

Comment: I know nothing about tools you use. However: what does "it is failing" mean? Perhaps you could/should describe what you did and what happened. Any errors? Which ones?

Comment: This is the sqoop command that I am executing . sqoop export  \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname:port/service \
--username username \
--password password \
--export-dir s3://employee/result/  \
--table employee \
--update-mode allowinsert \
--input-null-string '\\N'  \
--input-null-non-string '\\N' \
--outdir /home/hadoop/java \
--input-fields-terminated-by ',' \
--map-column-java "EMPLOYEE_ID=byte[]" \
--direct \
--verbose \
-m 1 and error is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No ResultSet method for Java type byte[]